# Which debug gems are most updated and maintained for rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I have been using `byebug` for debugging but it does not seem to be updated in 3 years. What other gems do you suggest for rails 7?

*Byebug is a simple to use and feature rich debugger for Ruby. It uses the TracePoint API for execution control and the Debug Inspector API for call stack navigation. Therefore, Byebug doesn't depend on internal core sources. Byebug is also fast because it is developed as a C extension and reliable because it is supported by a full test suite.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debug`. `debug` is the default gem for rails 7 and has some advantages like *high debug speed* and *remote debugging*. You can check [here](https://github.com/ruby/debug)